# Datatype to store range of IP addresses in Java

Tags: java

What data type is recommended to store range of IP addresses?

For eg,

```
"IP1":["12.21.31.0/24"],
"IP2":["13.96.210.122/28","12.33.116.17/21"]
```

The data is in JSON format. I have a java object that is parsing this JSON information. I am just not sure what data type to go ahead with in the Java class. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [InetAddress class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) would be the ideal type store IP addresses. It is a lot more than you've asked for here. But would be useful for getting IP from name/address or the other way round.

Since you are using CIDR masks not supported by INetAddress you'll need other types

Code sample using Apache [SubnetUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html)

```
String subnet = "12.21.31.0/24";
SubnetUtils utils = new SubnetUtils(subnet);
utils.getInfo().isInRange(address);
```

Code sample using [CIDRUtils](https://github.com/edazdarevic/CIDRUtils/blob/master/CIDRUtils.java)

```
CIDRUtils cidrUtils = new CIDRUtils("10.21.31.0/24");
String networkAddress = cidrUtils.getNetworkAddress();
String broadcastAddress = cidrUtils.getBroadcastAddress();
```

Comment: Can you give me an example to use InetAddress for the above IP addresses?

Comment: I don't think `InetAddress` will store CIDR format address ranges?

Comment: @msandiford You are right. For CIDR ranges she'll need something like [SubNetUtils (Apache)] (https://github.com/edazdarevic/CIDRUtils/blob/master/CIDRUtils.java) or [CIDRUtils](https://github.com/edazdarevic/CIDRUtils/blob/master/CIDRUtils.java)

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses can be represented as 32-bit integers (128-bit for IPv6).  So, you could simply treat ranges as ranges of integers.  You could then consider a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), a bit mask, or some other data structure, depending on how you query.  Alternately, perhaps a [RangeSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html) of either integers or a IP address wrapper class you write that implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html?is-external=true) would be a good solution.